# Using websockets secure (wss) in angular ngx-mqtt to connect to mosquitto broker fails to connect

Tags: angular, websocket, mqtt, mosquitto, self-signed

I have an Angular 12 web application that retreives mqtt data from a mosquitto broker by subscribing to topics on the broker via websockets (ws) on port **9001**, which works.

I have now encrypted the incoming mqtt data from devices that publish to the broker by creating my own self signed certificate and keys by [following this guide.](http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mosquitto-tls/) This works fine and works on port **8883**.

I'm also trying to encrypt communications between the Angular webapp connnecting to my broker to retrieve data. So far in my connection settings I have enabled the protocol as websockets secure **(wss)** instead of the standard websockets **(ws)**:

```
export const MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS: IMqttServiceOptions = 
{
  hostname: '<BROKER IP>', 
  port: 9001,
  protocol: 'wss', 
  username: '<BROKER USERNAME>', 
  password: '<BROKER PASSWORD>'
};
```

I've adjusted my mosquitto.conf file to be the following, [thanks to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65961895/ngx-mqtt-connect-via-webapp-to-ssl-tls-mosquitto-broker), where the answer indicates you need to specify the certificates and keys for each listener, which in my case is 9001 for websockets and 8883 for encrypted mqtt:

```
persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d

allow_anonymous false

password_file /etc/mosquitto/pwfile

#TLS CONFIG
listener 8883
cafile /etc/mosquitto/certs/mqtt_ca.crt
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/mqtt_srv.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/mqtt_srv.key
tls_version tlsv1.2

listener 9001
protocol websockets
cafile /etc/mosquitto/certs/mqtt_ca.crt
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/mqtt_srv.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/mqtt_srv.key
```

However when I look to my browser (Which is Brave and Firefox) I get the following errors in the console:

[image]

If I use normal websockets **(ws)** in the Angular webapp to connect to the broker it works fine, but obviously it's not encrypted then.

I have ensured that on my broker I have allowed incoming connections from ports 9001 and 8883 on the OS and router firewall.

I have no idea why this might be the case, any help would be appreicated, thanks.

I just tried to import the same self signed certificate CA mqtt_ca.crt I use on my mosquitto broker into the browsers cert store, which on MacOS brings up the Keychain. I marked it as trusted but I'm still getting connection errors.

I'm not sure if i did it correctly but this is what I have in the Keychain, under the login tab:

[image]

This is  the option in brave I selected which opened up the Keychain window: [image]

I also tried in Firefox to import my mqtt_ca.crt but again I get the same connection errors:

[image]

I've also had a deeper look into the Network portion of the browser dev tools and have came across this error:

```
SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG
```

[image]

But I'm not sure what it means.

Also to add, when I created my CA certificate key I used -aes256 with 4096 bits intead of the -des3 2048 bits used in the guide. I don't know if this would be related to these issues I'm having but my understanding is that des3 is an old insecure standard.

Comment: Is the page being loaded via http or https (if so is it using the same host/certificate as the broker)? And have you imported your self signed certificate into the browsers cert store?

Comment: Hi, at the moment my web application is just running locally for testing, also when it is deployed to a webserver it's only using http for the tme being. I wasn't aware of the browsers cert store, would this be an option under the browsers settings? And would my mqtt_ca.crt need to be imported into it? Or the mqtt_srv.crt? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When accessing a resource via JavaScript (e.g. the Javascript MQTT client) the browser will NOT prompt you to manually accept a self signed certificate like it does when you load a webpage.

You have a few options:

1. ensure the page hosting the MQTT client is also loaded via HTTPS using the same certificate as the broker. This will get the browser to prompt you to accept the risk of connecting with the self signed cert which should then carry over to the MQTT WebSocket connection.
2. import the self signed certificate into your browsers cert store and mark it as trusted. This is only really an option for developing as you would need to do it for ALL browsers that will ever access the site. Which cert you import depends on how you've created the certs, but if you have a CA cert then import that one.

Comment: Hi, that makes more sense now, however I still seem to be getting the same connection errors using your option 2. I have a feeling I did something incorrectly but I've updated my queestion to show what I've tried. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, not a mac user so can't say how the keystore trust stuff works.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll do a bit more searching but I think i'm heading in the right direction.

Comment: I tried to do the same with Firefox which didn't bring up the Keychain this time, but once again get those same connecton errors. I'm not sure if you'd know if I imported the key correctly into Firefox?

Comment: It's been a long time since I've had to do this (I tend to play with real LetsEncrypt certs these days) but this walk through looks right https://javorszky.co.uk/2019/11/06/get-firefox-to-trust-your-self-signed-certificates/

Comment: Yeah I did what the guide said, but i'm still getting those connection errors. I have no idea what's wrong. Strange.

Comment: Then it's hard to say more without seeing the full errors (probably in the network tab of the browser tools) and your certificates (only other thing is that cert contains valid SAN entries for both the machine DNS name and IP address).

Comment: I found another error in the Network portion of the browsers dev tools and have updated my question again.